# Robot arm programming, transformation of coordinate system

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a project in which i need make a matlab based simulation of a robotic arm.

[img http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/4512/l5mx.png](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/4512/l5mx.png)

The first part sits in the origin, and can rotate around the Z axis in the world coordinate system. This joint is called joint1. The next joint, joint2 is displaced 0.8m in the Z direction of the coordinate system of part 1. It will rotate around the Y axis of the coordinate system of part2. Joint3 is displaced 0.6m in the Z direction of the csystem of part2. It will rotate around the y axis of the csystem of part3. The end of part3 is displaced 0.7m in the Z direction of csystem of part3.

Now, lets try to do some matrices of this. I'm quite sure i'm doing something wrong with these. The coordinates will be in homogenous form, so v = [v,1].

```
T_Wto1 = [cos(alpha(1)), -sin(alpha(1)), 0 , 0;
          sin(alpha(1)), cos(alpha(1)),  0 , 0;
          0,             0,              1 , 0.8;
          0,             0,              0,  1];

T_1to2 = [cos(alpha(2)),  0, sin(alpha(2)), 0;
          0,              1, 0,             0;
          -sin(alpha(2)), 0, cos(alpha(2)), 0.6;
          0,              0, 0,             1];

T_2to3 = [cos(alpha(3)),  0, sin(alpha(3)), 0;
          0,              1, 0,             0;
          -sin(alpha(3)), 0, cos(alpha(3)), 0.7;
          0,              0, 0,             1];
```

For alpha(1) = 0, alpha(2) = alpha(3) = pi/2

First of all. If i use p1 = T_Wto1*[0,0,0,1]', i get [0,0,0.8,1]', so far so good. Then, T_1to2*[0,0,0.8,1]' gives [0.8,0,0.6,1]' (it is now displaced 0.8 in the X direction, which is really 0.8 in the Z direction, because of the rotation). Now, say that i want to transform this back to world coordinates. It **should** say [0.6,0,0.8], but i'm unsure on how to do that. If you just take the inverse of the matrix T_Wto2 (a product of T_Wto1 and T_1to2), you just get the origin [0,0,0,1] back. What are you supposed to do to make it back into world coordinates again?

Also, are the transformation matrices correct?

Comment: This sounds like more of a maths/geometry problem then a programming problem.  Why don't you try with a simpler set-up first, and then extend to multiple components?

Comment: Apart from that you are wrong here, as you actually got stucked in the underlying math of your problem: Try to put everything in a single matrix and invert it then. I've never calculated a roboter arm, but similar problems, it should work.

Comment: You know the inverse of the transformation matrix is equal to its transpose because it is orthogonal. so don't be afraid about calculating the inverse.